# Convert String to Object in PowerShell

Tags: json, string, powershell, object, hashtable

I get a string from a Web-Request and I want to get a specific value from this response.
The string of the response looks like:

```
[
    "BeginOfEnumerable",
    [
        {
            "Classification": [
                "/",
                "/Document/",
                "/Document/Engineering-Document/"
            ],
            "FieldValues": {
                "/0": "123456789",
                "/2": "55667788"
            },
            "Key": "urn:key:Document:123456789"
        }
    ],
    "EndOfEnumerable"
]
```

How do I get the value "123456789" from the line `"Key": "urn:key:Document:123456789"`?
The value has no specific syntax and can look like "12345-XY", "asdfgh", etc.
Is there a way to convert the valid Json-String above to an object (Json, HasTable, JArray, ...) and get the wanted value?
Or is better to get the value by string-operations like substring etc.?

Comment: You can simply pass it to `ConvertFrom-Json | %{ $_.FieldValues }` through a pipe.

Comment: Or store it in variable like `$myjson=$("web request"  | ConvertFrom-Json)` and use `$myjson.fieldvalues."/0"`.

Comment: You can also target specifically the line with `($myjson[1] | Where-Object -Property Key -eq "urn:key:Document:123456789" ).FieldValues."/0"`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. `$json = $responseString | ConvertFrom-Json` always runs in my catch block.... But the string, which I want to convert is valid, if I check it in a json validator???

Comment: Instead of `Invoke-WebRequest` you can also use `Invoke-RestMethod`. This method automatically converts the JSON response to a `PSCustomObject`.

Comment: The JSON you have provided in your question is valid. I guess there is something wrong with what you get in `$responseString`. Follow the useful advice of @Alex_P, use directly `Invoke-RestMethod` to get your `[PSCustomObject]`.

Comment: @Alex_p & Zilog80: Thank you very much for your answers. I already use the Invoke-RestMethod, but unfortunately I have to convert the response to a string and truncate the first four characters, because there are four question marks. Unfortunately I can't influence the received answer from the RestApi :( I already implemented the exact same query in C#.Net and first truncated the answer and then transferred it to JArray (Json.Net, Linq) where I read the wanted value... So the original response is : `????[ "BeginOfEnumerable",[ ...`

Comment: Then, can you try `$response.Content.Substring(4) | ConvertFrom-Json` when using Invoke-WebRequest?

Comment: @Theo: Thank you for your answer.
If I try `$response.Content.Substring(4) | ConvertFrom-Json` I run in my ctach blog. :(
For now, I'm using `$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri` ... and various string functions like
`$responseString = $response | ConvertTo-Json
$responseString = $responseString.Substring(4)
$searchTerm1 = "key:Document:"
$Pos1String = $responseString.IndexOf($searchTerm1)
$responseString1 = $responseString.Substring($Pos1String + $searchTerm1.Length)
$Pos2String = $responseString1.IndexOf('\') 
$docId = $responseString1.Substring(0, $Pos2String)`